# HTML object tag over Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, scriptcam

I'm currently using scriptcam.js to embed webcam capture in a webpage.

When i open bootstrap modal the modal appear under the webcam object.

[image]

This is the code generated by scriptcam.js to load webcam capture by a flash object.

[image]

I'm trying to play with z-index but it's not working.

Can someone have an idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index won't work and i don't know why!

Here is my workaround to solve this problem.

I use jquery to hide and show webcam on modal open / close.

```
/**
 * Hide and display webcam object on modal open / close.
 */
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#webcam1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#webcam3").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#webcam1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#webcam3").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: Nice workaround!  Used it for my project for which I was having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the z-index of the modal and video as follows:

for video --> z-index: 3040; 
for modal --> z-index: 3050;

If it doesn't work, try increasing the z-index for the modal.